Is there a way to assign indexes to spawned instances of a class?
I am currently writing a natural selection simulation where, prey and predators can be spawned in and if the two instances collide, the program should run a subroutine and delete that specified prey from the program. The predator and prey classes are stored in lists:
Private Predator As New List(Of PredatorClass)
Private Organism As New List(Of OrganismClass)

And the next part of my code should involve locating the indexes of the specified predator and prey at the time of their collision.
However, I am writing this program out in Visual Basic Windows Form App (.NET Framework) and I am having a hard time adding the specified indexes at the creation of the predator / prey organisms at their creation.
Public Sub AddOrganism(OrganismAdded As OrganismClass)
    Organism.Add(OrganismAdded)
End Sub
Public Sub AddPredator(PredatorAdded As PredatorClass)
    Predator.Add(PredatorAdded)
End Sub

Could I get some assistance on this, I am stumped and do not know what to do and my programming skills are not very strong. Thank you.
I had tried creating an enumerable range at the classes' creation to add these values on but the could did not accept it as the list was a list of classes and not an assignable data type. I was hoping it would add values to the classes so the program could differentiate between each instance.
Private Predator As New List(Of PredatorClass)(Enumerable.Range("", 25))
Private Organism As New List(Of OrganismClass)(Enumerable.Range("", 25))


Consider giving your lists plural names: Organisms and Predators rather than Organism and Predator.

It depends whether you simply want the list index which can change if you remove an object with a lower index from the list or whether you want a unique id which does not depend on the position in the list.

You can declare a shared field in the class that stores the next available index or Id. I will call it Id, as it will not necessarily be equal to the list index if you add or remove items from the list.
The shared field exist once and is shared among all the class instances (objects). You can then assign and increment the next Id in the constructor Sub New().
Public Class Predator
    Private Shared _nextId As Integer

    Public ReadOnly Property Id As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        Id = _nextId
        _nextId += 1
    End Sub
End Class

The following Console test...
For i As Integer = 0 To 4
    Dim pred = New Predator()
    Console.WriteLine(pred.Id)
Next i
Console.ReadKey()

... prints
0
1
2
3
4


If you have an object and want to find its index in a list, you can use IndexOf:
Dim index As Integer = Organism.IndexOf(org)

where, in this example, org is an OrganismClass instance.
